# How to handle users pressing back button too quickly after pushing a viewController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Usually after the viewController is pushed, I want to do certain things. In add phone feature, for example, I would open edit business and set the focus to the phone field.

If after viewController is pushed users press back button too quickly the app crash.

What's the standard way to do so?

This is the code:

```
+(BGBusinessEditViewController *) pushNewEditViewControllerWithBizandReturnValue: (Business *)biz withNavController :(UINavigationController *) nav andSelectPhone:(BOOL) selectPhoneAfterward
{
    BGBusinessEditViewController * editBusiness = [[BGBusinessEditViewController alloc]init];
    //[editBusiness view];//load the stuff first
    [nav vPushViewController:editBusiness animated:YES andPerformBlock:^{
        if (biz) {
            editBusiness.biz=biz; //viewDidload must be called first before setting bizs
        }
        if (selectPhoneAfterward)
        {
            [editBusiness selectPhone];
        }
    }];

    return editBusiness;
}

-(void) selectPhone
{
    NSIndexPath * ipth =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:BGBusinessEditTextPhoneNumber inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: ipth animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:ipth];
}
```

Basically I created a category in nav View Controller that will run code only when the navigation controller already reach `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;`

Comment: what does pushing back button quickly has anything to do with crashing ???

Comment: can you post the code of back button of second VController, viewDidLoad of 1st VController and if implemeted viewWillAppear in 1st VC that too..

Comment: The back button has no code. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Hide the back button until `viewDidAppear`, and then unhide it.

Comment: I think error still happen even if user press back after viewDidAppear